# 箭牌 vs 诏书: emperor's decree

Tags: characters

I'm thinking about a mnemonic for 令, and my wife mentioned that in former times the emperor's orders were written on tablets called 箭牌. However, I cannot find any information about this word, and the Google image search does not yield any tablets. How are these tablets referred to in Chinese?

I now that there's also 诏书, but this seems to relate more to orders written on paper. Am I right?

I tried to find a translation or even the right word by googling "emperor order tablet ", but nothing showed up. As I'm not a native English speaker: Am I missing the right word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are talking about `令牌` and `诏书`.

`令牌` is something like badge. It doesn't have any order on it, but just used to identify the person who carry it.

`诏书` is orders written on paper, bamboo or something else.

Comment: +1.  I would like to mention that some 令牌 in certain time in hitrory can be a form of giving order